# CakePHP 3 - Save function not generating primary key for database

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I have an application I'm working on with Cake 3 and I've baked a bunch of things to get the lay of the land as I'm newer to Cake.

When going to the baked add view for one of my models, filling out the form and submitting, the entry is added to the database but the primary key is blank on the entry.  I've been doing some research and in the table class for Cake, I know that it's supposed to be created during the save method.  However, I haven't overridden save or anything like that, so I'm a little confused as to why it's not generating the ID field for the primary key.

I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction towards some steps that might help me debug this.  Thanks!

Comment: What type is your `id` field in your MySQL table?

Comment: @InigoFlores It's a varchar(36), would that be possibly affecting it?

Comment: Please post the code for the add view.

Comment: @InigoFlores The database was pre-existing from a version of the application running CakePHP 1.3, so I'm fairly certain the schema is okay.  When I baked my MVC for a few pages, I did not alter anything.  The add view is just the boilerplate code from the back.

Comment: Does your form include  `echo $this->Form->input('id')`? Is it rendering as a text input field?

Comment: @InigoFlores Hi Inigo, I figured out what the exact issue is, however I'm still fuzzy on a solution!  I've added an edit to my question with the new info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Cookbook 3.x](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions):

> Rather than using an auto-increment key as the primary key, you may also use `char(36)`. CakePHP will then use a unique 36 character UUID (`Text::uuid`) whenever you save a new record using the `Table::save()` method.

Try converting you `id` field in your MySQL table from

```
VARCHAR(36)
```

to

```
CHAR(36)
```

Comment: Gave it a shot and the documentation makes sense, but no luck.  I'm guessing then the problem has to be somehow unrelated to the type of the field

Comment: @MasonDixonLine delete the contents of `/app/tmp/cache/models` and try saving again.

Comment: No luck after emptying the cache.

Comment: @MasonDixonLine see if you can post the code for the form

Comment: Hi Inigo, I apologize in advance but your answer actually was correct.  The ID on my one table is referenced on 3 other tables (foreign key is possibly the right term?  Sorry I'm newer to database lingo) and I forgot to also make them char rather than varchar also.  I believe everything is fixed.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it! VARCHAR(36) used to work in CakePHP 1.x, but maybe support was removed for performance reasons. Correct; when a foreign key on a table points to the primary key on another table, we are dealing with `hasMany` or `hasOne` relationships.